# Found shared references to a collection: when using transactions in parallel from same user session

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using hibernate 3.3 with spring 3.0.5 and using JPA transaction manager.
My scenario is a ui page invoking two get methods on service layer to render two regions in UI, Requests are parallel ajax requests. The get methods in service layer return two 'separate' lists of same entity.

```
List<Car> getCarsA();
List<Car> getCarsB();
```

I have configured JPA transaction manager as below:

```
<tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
```

Problem :  when the hibernate/JPA calls flush after each service method is over, there is potentially some collection (via many-to-many mappings) which is shared between the two lists returned by the methods and hence the exception. I am also using OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.
I do not run into this error if I call the methods serially.

Answer (score 0):

The Hibernate session object is not thread-safe. You either must use an own session instance per thread or you must synchronise the access to the session instance with the java `synchronized` block.

In a web environment you should use at least one hibernate session per browser session. Access by the same browser session can be `synchronized` or also use more than one session (when fetching different regions of the UI concurrently as you do it, I would synchronise it with `synchronized` except if one query needs a quite long time where the other queries should not wait for).

Attention: Updates in one session are not directly visible in other session (for the case the instance already is cached in the other session).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and the explanation. Could you please elaborate how can I make my service methods synchronised ? I am using JPA entitymanager which in itself is not thread safe I believe. So do you suggest making access to em itself syncronized ?